# $P(E|F) + P(E|F^{c})=1$ does it make sense?

Tags: probability

$P(E|F) + P(E|F^{c})=1$ does it make sense for any $E$ and $F$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 5):

No. Just take $E$ and $F$ (and $F^c$) independent and you'll get $2P[E]$.

On the other hand $P[E\mid F]+P[E^c\mid F]=1$

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. $P(E|F) + P(E^C|F)=1$ makes sense, because:
$$P(E|F)+P(E^C|F)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}+\frac{P(E^C\cap F)}{P(F)}=\frac{P(F)}{P(F)}=1.$$

**Example 1 (con):** $100$ students took an exam. $80\%$ students had studied for the exam and $90\%$ of them passed it. $20\%$ students had not studied and $25\%$ of them passed it.

Let $E=\{$passing exam$\}$, $F=\{$study for exam$\}$. Then:
$$P(E|F)=0.9; P(E|F^C)=0.25 \Rightarrow P(E|F)+P(E|F^C)=1.15>1;\\
=========================================\\
P(E|F)=0.9; P(E^C|F)=0.1 \Rightarrow P(E|F)+P(E^C|F)=1.$$

**Example 2 (pro):** $100$ students took an exam. $80\%$ students had studied for the exam and $90\%$ of them passed it. $20\%$ students had not studied and $10\%$ of them passed it.

Let $E=\{$passing exam$\}$, $F=\{$study for exam$\}$. Then:
$$P(E|F)=0.9; P(E|F^C)=0.1 \Rightarrow P(E|F)+P(E|F^C)=1;\\
=========================================\\
P(E|F)=0.9; P(E^C|F)=0.1 \Rightarrow P(E|F)+P(E^C|F)=1.$$